# Update flash player for Opera

Tags: flash

I am using Opera 37.0 on Ubuntu 15.10 (64 bit).
Opera shows that the Flash Player needs to be updated.
I cannot find any option of updating the plugin. Tried Prefrence-- but there is no advnaced settings.

Comment: try this command in the terminal: sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin

 **I couldnt leave comments because i did not have 50 reputation

Comment: Sorry, did not work out.

Comment: it did install? opera has some information about flash plugin for linux systems http://www.opera.com/docs/linux/plugins/install/

Answer (score 1):

Install the package `adobe-flashplugin` from Canonical Partner.
This is really easy and you even get automatic updates.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check if flash player is properly installed:

```
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --status
```

In new Opera from 15 version the only most appropriate way to flash player work is using **PPAPI** flash player interface supported by default in **multiverse** repository in Ubuntu, not adobe-flashplugin and you don't need install alternative repository.
First install flash player :

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

It will download full chromium browser to unpack flash player plug-in.

```
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

and last:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To check if flash player is installed properly :

```
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --status
```

after that flash player can be verified on adobe site [here](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/).

Full description how to install this plug-in [is here](http://ubuntu.pl/forum/viewtopic.php?f=152&t=180008).

Comment: Downvoted this answer since it's obsolete (`pepperflashplugin-nonfree` is broken).

Comment: pepperflashplugin-nonfree is not broken is not provided with Google Chromium and here is [solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/856329/how-now-install-newest-flash-player-in-opera-and-chromium-guide).

Comment: Yes, [it's broken](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1632870). Since `adobe-flashplugin` in Canonical Partner provides the latest version, it does not make sense to point users to a complicated workaround.

Comment: Case is open You don't  know what will be happen with PPAPI, now is only one solution what I provided, and You cannot decide for other people what is proper, let them decide for themselves.